# How to include telugu language in django forms

Tags: django, django-templates

**Model:**

```
class Application(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    father_or_husband_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    nominee_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    job = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**Forms:**

```
class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = ('full_name', 'father_or_husband_name', 'nominee_name', 'date_of_birth',
                  'job', 'address', 'mobile_no')
```

In my template the fields display as:

Full Name:
Father Or Husband Name:
Nominee Name:
Date Of Birth:
Job:
Address:
Mobile No:

I want these fields in  my native language Telugu.

Answer (score -2):

Add verbose_name like this:

```
class Application(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name="Full Name")
```

You can also see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/

Comment: How does `verbose_name` help him ?